# Are scroll view images removed from memory after they are scrolled to the left?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview which is continuously scrolling . The scroll view has the images with full size as the screen 320 * 480. So only one image is seen on the screen at a time. The scroll view is continuously scrolling while my application is in running state. While profiling the application I found that the instead of image added to the scrollview my memory is not increasing. My question is after image is scrolled out from the scroll view is it removed from the memory or do I need to do it explicitly ?

Comment: it will still remain in memory you have to remove the images from the non-visible part of scrollview programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won`t removed from the memory automatically.

There are 2 ways to handle it.

The 1st way is : You can keep only 3 imageView on the scrollView. and add or remove other imageView in the scrollView by the scrollView`s delegate such as

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

The 2nd way is : to keep a 3 pages scrollView , and change the image when the scroll is scrolling.you can see the demo : https://github.com/smallqiang/cycleScrollerView

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use UITableView, rotated by 90, with cells, rotated by -90. In this case only visible pictures will live in memory.